# How to give right permission for zeppelin user

Tags: hdfs, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

When I ran some PySpark queries in Zeppelin against an EMR cluster I have in AWS, I got the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=zeppelin, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
```

I guess I can just give a Write permission to this user (Zeppelin) but the user already has its own home directory in HDFS (/user/zeppelin). Why is it trying to write to the root directory ("/"). I am not so sure I am interpreting the error message properly though.

Comment: Instead of giving ownership of root to the zeppelin user. Just use the path `hdfs:///user/zeppelin/WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_WRITE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up giving a write permission for the user "zeppelin" like this:

```
sudo su hdfs
hdfs dfs -chown zeppelin /
```

Comment: You could instead use the "home" space of user zeppelin instead of giving it the ownership of root.